# Dateformat with nullable variable

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
 startWeekDate = startWeekDate == null ? DateTimeHelpers.calcMondayDate(DateTime.Now) : DateTimeHelpers.calcMondayDate(startWeekDate.Value);
 DateTime endWeekDate = startWeekDate.Value.AddDays(6);
```

startWeekDate is a parameter that is nullable. This works good, but I want to format it with: String.Format("{d:0}", .... ) but when I slap that around it I get error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?

How shall I fix this problem?

/M

EDIT:

I'm trying to add this to the function instead, since it should always return dateformat without clock, but I get same error there with this code:

```
    public static DateTime calcMondayDate(DateTime input)
    {
        int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime monday = String.Format("{d:0}", input.AddDays(delta));

        return monday;
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

hmm, but input is DateTime, why does it complain about it being string?

Comment: What exact nullable type is startWeekDate?

Comment: public .....(DateTime? startWeekDate)

Comment: What would you like the formatted string to be if the var value is null?

Comment: Oh, wait, are you trying to do startWeekDate = String.Format(... )?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've shown the code that *doesn't* have a problem, but not the code that *does* have a problem. Please show the code which doesn't compile. It *sounds* like you're trying to assign a `DateTime?` variable a string value, e.g.

```
startWeekDate = string.Format(...);
```

That's definitely not going to work. What would you really want it to do with the formatted value once you've got it as a string? Use it where you want a string, not where you want a `DateTime?`.

One thing to add - your first line can be expressed more simply:

```
startWeekDate = DateTimeHelpers.calcMondayDate(startWeekDate ?? DateTime.Now);
```

EDIT: Now you've posted your code, it's clear why it's not working - as suspected, you're trying to assign a string value to a `DateTime` variable.

**DateTime values don't have a format**. They're like numbers - they have a value which isn't inherently formatted. It's like 0x10 and 16 are the same number, just written differently.

Now it sounds like you're just trying to return the date without the time - which is better done as:

```
return input.AddDays(delta).Date;
```

The `Date` property returns a `DateTime` with the same date, but midnight as the time.

On a side note, it's a shame that .NET has such a restricted set of date/time types, so that you can't *really* represent the idea of a time-less date. I'm trying to [fix this situation](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time), but it'll be a while before it bears fruit...

Comment: To follow up on this, DateTime variables have no format.  They simply contain a value that represents the date.  If you care about formatting you set that at output time.

Comment: @Jon Is SO your 20% project...or have you invented the SkeetBot that posts answers and updates for you? :-P I can only hope to have that kind of efficiency one day.

Answer (score 1):

The error is "cannot convert string to DateTime".

Whch is exactly what this line is attempting to do:

```
DateTime monday = String.Format("{d:0}", input.AddDays(delta));
```

As I said in my comment above, you format at output time.  Internally a datetime is just a number, it has no concept of format.  You should simply return the `input.AddDays(delta)`

Answer (score 0):

You get the compilation error because you have declared startWeekDate as a DateTime, but string.Format returns a string. One possible remedy is to change the declaration:

```
string endWeekDate = string.Format("{d:0}", startWeekDate.Value.AddDays(6));
```

However, now `endWeekDate` is a string, so you migh want to change the code a bit to keep it as is, and then introduce a new variable which is the string representation of that variable. Whether or not that is a good idea depends on the context.